# ¿Por qué mysql no me deja crear una llave primaria?

Tags: mysql

Estoy intentando crear una llave primaria para un tipo de dato varchar,
a la vez que estoy haciendo que tenga un 'id' auto incrementable,
el 'id' es para que los registros estén ordenados numéricamente,
la 'clave' es para que con código php se genere una clave aleatoria.
Mi sentencia sql es el siguiente:

```
CREATE TABLE cotizacion(
    id_cotizacion int AUTO_INCREMENT,
    clave varchar(15) not null,
    nombre_cliente varchar(150) not null,
    telefono varchar(15),
    correo varchar(30),
    direccion varchar(150),
    fecha_cot date
);

alter table cotizacion
  add primary key (clave);
```

Aclaro que no soy bueno en bases de datos.
Ahora bien, mysql no me permite que el campo 'clave' se haga llave primaria,
¿pueden decirme qué estoy haciendo mal? o ¿por qué no me permite hacerlo?

Comment: Que error te muestra ? Es un error comun, si creas un campo auto_increment este debe ser la primary key

Comment: @MateoGuio me marca el error: "#1075 - Puede ser solamente un campo automatico y este debe ser definido como una clave"

Comment: Exacto te esta diciendo que solo puede haber un campo auto incrementable y ese debe ser la llave primaria Bro obligatoriamente

Comment: Pero entonces cómo haré que 'clave' sea una llave foránea??? ¿La convierto en un índice?

Comment: No será que te falta definirle un valor DEFAULT para que te permita crear la PK?

Comment: Yo ya lo he intentado varias veces y no se puede asignar una llave primaria a un campo, si hay un campo auto incrementable ya en la tabla. Te dira este error: #1075 - Puede ser solamente un campo automatico y este debe ser definido como una clave"

Answer (score 0):

Hola amigo tienes una incoherencia, no puedes crear un campo auto_increment y asignarle la llave primaria a otro campo. Lo que puedes hacer es asignarle una llave foranea pero no una primaria. Exactamente para que quieres que la clave sea la llave primaria ?

```
DROP TABLE cotizacion;
DROP TABLE producto_cotizacion;
CREATE TABLE cotizacion(
    id_cotizacion int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT,
    clave varchar(15) not null,
    nombre_cliente varchar(150) not null,
    telefono varchar(15),
    correo varchar(30),
    direccion varchar(150),
    fecha_cot date
);

CREATE TABLE producto_cotizacion(
id_prod_ct int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    clave varchar(15),
    id_coti int(11) not null,
    cantidad int(11),
    descripcion varchar(160),
    factor varchar(30),
    contenido varchar(30),
    precio_unitario decimal(10,2),
    sub_total decimal(10,2) 
    );
```

Lo que puedes hacer es añadir una llave foranea asi:

```
ALTER TABLE producto_cotizacion ADD FOREIGN KEY (id_coti) REFERENCES cotizacion(id_cotizacion) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

Asi en la tabla articulos, en cada registro guardaras el id de la cotizacion correspondiente, quedo atento.

Comment: Considero que no es una incoherencia, el campo 'clave' es necesario que se haga llave

Comment: No hay manera de hacer lo que quieres amigo, puede ser una llave pero foranea, apuntando a otra tabla, tal vez pueda ayudarte si me explicas por que requieres que sea una clave ?

Comment: Que 'clave' sea una llave principal es para que sea una relación de 1 a *, porque, una cotización lleva varios productos. Por ejemplo, tengo una cotización, y esa cotización tiene varios artículos, y lo que quiero hacer es apuntar a la clave de esa cotización principal, lo cual esos artículos pertenecen. ¿Me expliqué?

Comment: Entiendo amigo puedes hacerlo añadiendo una llave foranea a la tabla articulos apuntando a la tabla cotizacion.

Comment: Amigo ya entendi tu problema, edite mi respuesta para que en tu tabla articulos halla una llave foranea que apunte a la tabla cotizacion. Asi una cotizacion podra tener varios articulos

Comment: Si gustas puedo ayudarte a solucionarlo, entra al siguiente link para que puedas mostrarme tus tablas y yo mostrarte como hacer lo que necesitas: https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=ggzE7Sr1T5

Comment: Ya hice que 'clave' de la tabla cotización, sea un índice, para que en la tabla de artículos, el campo 'clave' (mismo nombre) sea una llave foránea, espero que funcione. Agradezco su tiempo de usted por aclarar mis ideas.

Comment: Sólo que añadí otras sentencias en la llave foránea: así "ALTER TABLE producto_cotizacion ADD FOREIGN KEY (clave) REFERENCES cotizacion(clave)
    on DELETE RESTRICT on UPDATE CASCADE"

Comment: Ya edite mi respuesta Bro el link donde estaba trabajando, hice un mal comando y no sirvio jajaja, pero pruebalo ahora